# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, mocha.js, chai

```
"use strict";
import 'mocha';

let chai = require('chai');
chai.use(require('chai-json-schema'));
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Parent /search', async () => {

    it('Positive tests', function(done) {
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/search?language=en&country=ca&query=pink')
            .end(function(err: any , res: any) {
                should.equal(err, null);
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.should.be.json;
                res.body[0].should.have.property('products');//error reading should()
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

---------------------------GET: Response--------------------

```
{"products": [
{
"id": "2448848",
"name": "Pink 'Pink is Punk' Sweatshirt",
"seo_keyword": {
"en": "pink-pink-is-punk-sweatshirt"
},
"sku": "181476M204001",
"brand_id": 485,
"brand_name": "Valentino",
"brand_seo_keyword": "valentino",
"brand": {
"name": "Valentino",
"seo_keyword": "valentino"
},
"category_id": 208,
"category_name": "SWEATSHIRTS",
"category": {
"name": "SWEATSHIRTS",
"seo_keyword": "sweatshirts"
},
"gender": "men",
"price": {
"currency": "CAD",
"format": "$%s",
"full_format": "$%s CAD",
"regular": 760,
"sale": 403,
"discount": 47,
"country": "ca",
"display": 403
}
}
```

I am trying to validate the attributes in my response from the server(GET). I encounter `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined`. I have installed all the assertion libraries for chai/mocha, and included these in my file, but I can't figure out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `res.body[0]` in your sample? Looking to your GET response (that is not a valid JSON, I guess there should be `]}` at the end, right?) I would suggest to try `res.body.should.have.property('products');` instead.

---

To get for example 'sku' of product item you may do following:

```
const product = body.products[0];
product.should.have.property('sku').and.to.be.a('string');
```

You need to create an object explicitly because of chai augments Object.prototype.

Comment: yes, sorry there was ']}' in the end of the json. Thanks. it works for products but if i have to validate id or  sku , whats the syntax for it. I am using 
`res.body.should.have.property('products')
      .which.is.an('object')
      .and.has.property('id');` 
but it gives me  <Uncaught AssertionError: expected [ Array(60) ] to be an object
>. If you can answer this, my problem is solved. Thanks again.